# How to make Dialogflow detecting multiple occurrence of entity in the same utterrance

Tags: chatbot, named-entity-recognition, dialogflow-cx, nlu

I am using DialogFLOW to create a simple chatbot.

I create a FLOW that consists of StartPage and Location Page.
in Location page I need to fill form of locations. So, I used the entity `@sys.geo-city`. In location page, I create a parameter Location. In routes, I added GetLocation intent and `$page.params.status = "FINAL"` intent.
The agent asks the user to provide 1 or few locations.

Everything is working well when I give only one location. However, when the user enters more than 1 location, it returns only the first occurrence!

If you need I can provide some screen shots!

[image]